# Custom TextBox control: AppendLine

Tags: c#, inheritance, wpf

Is there any way to improve this simple addition to the textbox control: appending a new line?

```
class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public void AppendLine(string textData)
    {
        if (this.Text.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine) || this.Text == "")
        {
            this.AppendText(textData);
        }
        else
        {
            this.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + textData);
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a custom class, instead of writing this as an extension method?

Comment: Extention Methods sound like something I ought to know about, please expand or point me somewhere, thanks.

Comment: You could start with [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx): “Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I am thinking about changing / enhancing some code, I have usually two things (regarding the code for review) in mind:

1. Whenever there is some method that gets called in every if-else / switch-case, think about using some variable to make it single call. *(This includes same method on different objects of common type - not aplicable to this case, but for the record)*
2. Check all conditions *(and variables)*, if they are really required. *(This includes joined conditions, when one renders to be redundant because of another already met. Sometimes I see variables that are used to avoid `goto`, but it turns out it can be done without both by reorganizing it - again not aplicable to this code review, but for the check-list)*

My final solution would look like this:

```
class CustomTextBox : TextBox {
    public void AppendLine(string textToAppend) {
        string current = this.Text;
        if (current.Length > 0
        && !current.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
            textToAppend = Environment.NewLine + textToAppend;
        this.AppendText(textToAppend);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I have deleted all redundant / wrong parts. The check for empty text is needed, and `TextLength` is a property of WinForms TextBox, not the one in WPF.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to check for empty text, otherwise the first line will only be a new line and the text will start on line 2.

Comment: Also we have to check the text length using `this.Text.Length` - I cannot see a `this.TextLength` ?

Comment: You are right, it must be there. And TextLength is on WinForms TextBox, probably not on WPF version.

Answer (score 2):

I don't care for empty quotes designating an empty string. It should be replaced with `String.Empty`. It simply clarifies your intention and leaves no ambiguity that you perhaps forgot to put something in the quotes, or maybe even meant to put a space in there. Otherwise, I feel this is very simple and solid.

Comment: I just checked and Java does not have `String.EMPTY`. I'm a bit sad. ( I know it's a `C#` question, I just verified for `Java` )